# How to test RxJs4 streams containing promise chains

Tags: unit-testing, rxjs

I'm having difficulty grasping how to swap out a promise chain from my Rx stream so I can test it.

The snippet below is from the documentation of [RxJs createResolvedPromise](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/testing/testscheduler.md#rxtestschedulerprototypecreateresolvedpromiseticks-value) and has been enhanced with a chained `.then(()=>..)` to better simulate my code. When running this example the `.then()` is not applied to the results emitted.

```js
var scheduler = new Rx.TestScheduler();

// Create resolved promise
var xs = scheduler.createResolvedPromise(201, 'bar')
  .then(val => 'foo:'+val);

// Note we'll start at 200 for subscribe, hence missing the 150 mark
var res = scheduler.startScheduler(
  // fromPromise needs scheduler explicitly, see https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/issues/976
  () => Rx.Observable.fromPromise(xs, scheduler)
);

// expected: value to be foo:bar but got bar
console.log(res.messages.map(msg => `msg:@${msg.time} val:${msg.value}`));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/4.1.0/rx.all.js"></script>
```

It seems that the `.then()` is ignored when using the TestScheduler (although `createResolvedPromise` returns a Mock promise with implementation of .then to also return a MockPromise...).

The example above is heavily simplified, The real code would be something along:

```
const myStream = Rx.Observable.interval(100)
  .flatMap(() => doPromiseOne().then(res => doPromiseTwo(res)))
  .subscribe(console.log);
```

So what i am trying to attain in my test is that i can resolve `promiseOne` (using `createResolvedPromise`?) and let it flow through `doPromiseTwo` so i can observe the results.

Comment: Looks like an old [issue](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/issues/1183).

Comment: Can you not mock all `Promise`s down into a single call? `MockPromise` is meant to be just that a mock, it isn't a full implementation.